# Crawl website and get table data

Tags: php, regex, xpath, web-crawler

I have search and looked at a lot of examples on stackoverflow, but still cant get it to work.

I would like to crawl a website to get the position table of my sport club.

My problem is that I cant get the "tr" content from the table. In the start I used REGEX, but then I read that people wouldn't recommend it, so now I use XPath, but cant get it to work.

The page I want to crawl is: `http://resultater.dai-sport.dk/tms/Turneringer-og-resultater/Pulje-Stilling.aspx?PuljeId=104`

And the code I have right now is:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://resultater.dai-sport.dk/tms/Turneringer-og-resultater/Pulje-Stilling.aspx?PuljeId=104"); // or you could load from a string using loadHTML();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/table/thead/tbody/tr");

print_r($elements);
```

The result I am getting is: DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

Am I completely wrong?

Comment: You are looking for a `tbody` in a `thead`??

Comment: You probably want to limit by table id as well, in case there are multiple tables on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PeeHaa notice it, a `tbody` tag is not inside a `thead` tag (in a normal code). However, there is no `tbody` tag in the source code, then you can use:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//table/tr");
```

To extract your data from the site you can use this:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//table/tr[contains(@class,'sr')]");

$keys = array('nb', 'hold', 'k', 'v', 'u', 't', 'scoreA', 'scoreB', 'p');

foreach ($elements as $elt) {
    $results[] = array_combine($keys,
     preg_split('~^\s++|\s++$|\h*+\R\s*+-?\s*+~', $elt->textContent, null, 1)
    );
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($results, true);
```

Another way is to use `preg_match()` and to describe the structure of `textContent`. An example with the second link:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?<kampnr>     [0-9]++                    ) \s++
(?<dato>       [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ) \s++
(?>
    kl\. \s++
    (?<kl> [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} ) \s++
)?
(?<hjemmehold> .+?                        ) \h*+ \R \s++
(?<udehold>    .+?                        ) \h*+ \R \s++
(?<spillA>     .+?                        ) \h*+ \R \s++
(?<spillB>     .+?                        ) \h*+ \R \s++
(?>
    (?<resultatA> [0-9]++    ) \s*+ - \s*+
    (?<resultatB> [0-9]++    ) 
)? 
~xu
LOD;

foreach ($elements as $elt) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $elt->textContent, $match)) {
        foreach($match as $k=>$v) {
            if (is_numeric($k)) unset($match[$k]);
        }
        $result[] = $match;
    }                
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true);
```

Comment: Hello Casimir et Hippoolyte, I have one problem more. Maybe you can help there also:-) I also want to crawl the matchprogram - http://resultater.dai-sport.dk/tms/Turneringer-og-resultater/Pulje-Komplet-Kampprogram.aspx?PuljeId=104. But when I do it with the code you have provided me, it only gives me the first match, but fails in the others. If I change the parameter 1 in preg_split function to 0, it gives me all the others, but not the first:-/ And I would like to  get them all?

Comment: @AndreasBaran: An other way than preg_split, take a look at the edit. The 1 in the preg_split function is a shortcut for the option: PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY.